# List widget con map

Tags: lista, flutter, datos

necesito hacer una lista de widget que se repita tantas veces como datos hay rellenados en otra pagina con formulario que genera un array.

Se que tengo que hacerlo con un map pero soy novata y nunca hice uno.
Estos son los archivos:

Aquí se convierte en lista:

**user.secondaryHospitals = _selectedSecondaryHospitals.where((h) => h != null).toList();**

```
 _setEditProfile() async {
    String name = _nameController.text;
    String surname = _surnameController.text;
    String phone = _phoneController.text;
    String phoneShort = phoneNumberShort;
    String phoneIOSCode = defaultCountryCode;

    Hospital hospital = _selectedHospital!;
    Country country = finalCountryObject;
    Speciality speciality = finalSpecialityObject;
    List<dynamic> interests = _selectedInterestsIds;

bool isChecksms = checkSms!;
bool isCheckNotification = checkNotification!;

try {
  User user = await (_provider.editProfile(globals.user!.id.toString(), globals.user!.email.toString(), phone, phoneIOSCode, phoneShort, name,
      surname, hospital, country, speciality, interests, isChecksms, isCheckNotification));
  **user.secondaryHospitals = _selectedSecondaryHospitals.where((h) => h != null).toList();**
  globals.user = user;

  Navigator.pop(context);

  widget.updateProfile!();

  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return InfoDialog(
          alertTitle: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.info,
          alertText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.editProfileSaved,
        );
      });
} on ApiException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == HttpStatus.unauthorized) {
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => SessionExpiredDialog());
  } else {
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => GeneralApiErrorAlert(apiException: e));
  }
}
```

}

y lo que necesito es pasar esa lista a otra página para o hacer un ListView.Builder o hacer la lista de widgets que contengan esos datos de otra manera.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que `user.secondaryHospitals` viene siendo una lista, lo primero que tendrás que hacer es crear una variable que te liste el mapa:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> listHospitals = {};
```

Luego como estás asignando tu lista de objetos en esta variable `user.secondaryHospitals` tendras que hacer un bucle para poder agregar cada objeto:

```
    try {
  //código...
  //AQUI LA CONVIERTES EN LISTA ENTIENDO
  user.secondaryHospitals = _selectedSecondaryHospitals.where((h) => h != null).toList();

 //AQUÍ HACEMOS EL CICLO FOR
for(var item in user.secondaryHospitals){
  //AQUI AGREGAMOS EL HOSPITAL A LA LISTA DE MAPA
  listHospitals.add({'hospital': item})
}
 //código...
}
```

Con eso ya tendrías tu lista de mapa, y esa misma variable la puedes pasar como parámetro a la página donde quieras mostrar los datos.
Para poder acceder a los datos tienes que hacerlo de esta manera:

```
listHospitals[index]['hospital'].nombreVariable
```